# Not able to resize objects <HREF> + Media Query CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, href

I am having problems with resizing some buttons in my page because when you resize the page for the screen of a mobile phone and you try to click on them `<href "1.htm">`, they will do not do anything.

I know that it is a problem of the media query but I do not how to solve it.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>DaZPlayer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_files/styles.css">
      <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_files/menu.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="1"><img class="portada" src="index_files/DaZ-Player_v2.jpg"></a>


    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <nav class="nav">
    <input class="chk-nav" type="checkbox" id="btn-navbar" />
    <label for="btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></label>

    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" class="casa"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Inicio</a></li>
      <li>
        <!--- SI QUIERES PONER UNA FLECHA DEBES PONER  CLASS lbl-nav --->
          <label for="btn-subnav1">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>Canales
          </label>
          <input class="chk-nav" type="checkbox" id="btn-subnav1"/>


          <!--- ESTO ES POR SÍ QUIERES PONER MÁS COSAS ADENTRO DE UNA

          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Excel básico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diseño web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computación básica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fundamentos de programación</a></li>
          </ul>
          --->

      </li>
      <li>
          <label class="" for="btn-subnav2">
               <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>Nosotros
          </label>
          <input class="chk-nav" type="checkbox" id="btn-subnav2" />

          <!--- ESTO ES POR SÍ QUIERES PONER MÁS COSAS ADENTRO DE UNA

          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Excel básico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diseño web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computación básica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fundamentos de programación</a></li>
          </ul> --->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="casa"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Contáctenos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <!--- Ya Por fin Comenzamoz y salimos del Menu --->
  <h1 class="titulo_1">Canales de TV en Vivo</h1>
  <div id="contenedor1">
    <br>
    <a href="1" class="conexion"><img alt="" class="canales" src="img_canales/cnn.png"></a>
    <a href="2" class="conexion"><img alt="" class="canales" src="img_canales/rt1.png"></a>
    <a href="3" class="conexion"><img alt="" class="canales_mas_ancho" src="img_canales/todo_noticias.png"></a>
    <a href="4" class="conexion"><img alt="" class="canales_mas_ancho" src="img_canales/tlx_arg.png"></a>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

`menu.css`:

```
/*_________________________________________________________________

                      $RESET
____________________________________________________________________*/
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

                      $ESTILOS GENERALES
____________________________________________________________________*/
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.casa, label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  border-left: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.casa:hover, label:hover {
  color: #FFB503;
  border-left: 4px solid #049CF3;
}

.chk-nav {
  display: none;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

                      $NAV <nav class"nav"></nav>
____________________________________________________________________*/
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

                      $NAVBAR <ul class"nav-bar"></ul>
____________________________________________________________________*/
.navbar {
  width: 50%;
}
.navbar .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}

.sub-nav .casa {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.navbar > li {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position: relative;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

$ESTILOS PARA MODIFICAR EL LABEL SECUNDARIO DEL SUBMENU
____________________________________________________________________*/
.navbar .fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
}

/* 25BC es la flecha */
.lbl-nav:after {
  content: "\25BC";
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  left: 0;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

$ESTILOS PARA MODIFICAR EL LABEL PRINCIPAL O ICONO DE HAMBURGUESA
____________________________________________________________________*/
label[for="btn-navbar"] {
  padding: .5rem 1rem .5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
  color: #049CF3;
  background-color: #252525;
}
label[for="btn-navbar"]:hover {
  color: #E5E5E5;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

$ESTILOS PARA ESCONDER LA LISTA PRINCIPAL DEL MENU
____________________________________________________________________*/
.navbar {
  margin-left: -100%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  background-color: #252525;
}

.chk-nav:checked ~ .navbar {
  margin-left: 0;
}

/*_________________________________________________________________

$ESTILOS PARA ESCONDER LOS SUBMENUS
____________________________________________________________________*/
.navbar .sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

.chk-nav:checked ~ .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}

/****************_________________________________________________________________*******************

                                $ESTILOS PARA DESKTOP MEDIAQUERYS
****************____________________________________________________________________*****************/
@media all and (min-width: 49rem) {
  .casa, label {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }

           /*_________________________________________________________________

            $ESTILOS PARA NAVBAR
          ____________________________________________________________________*/
  .navbar {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .navbar > li {
    display: table-cell;
  }

  .chk-nav:checked ~ .navbar {
    margin: auto;
  }


          /*_________________________________________________________________

            $ESTILOS PARA ESCONDER EL ICONO DE HAMBURGUESA
          ____________________________________________________________________*/
  label[for="btn-navbar"] {
    display: none;
  }

          /*_________________________________________________________________

          $ESTILOS PARA el SUBMENU
          ____________________________________________________________________*/
  .navbar .sub-nav {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar > ul > li {
    position: relative;
  }

  .chk-nav:checked ~ .sub-nav {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar .sub-nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .sub-nav .casa {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }

          /*_________________________________________________________________

                  $ESTILOS PARA LOS ICONOS
            ____________________________________________________________________*/
  .navbar .fa {
    position: static;
    padding-right: .3rem;
  }

  .lbl-nav:after {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
  }

        /*_________________________________________________________________

                  $ESTILOS PARA EL MENU PRINCIPAL
         ____________________________________________________________________*/

         /* BORDES*/

  .navbar > li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 4px solid #049CF3;
  }

  .navbar > li > .casa:hover, label:hover {
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  }
}
```

`styles.css`:

```
    #contenedor1 {
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 70px;
    }



@media all and (max-width: 450px){
  .portada{
      width:100%;
  }
}

h1.titulo_1 {
  text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    }


/* CUANDO LA PANTALLA ES MENOR A 1000px PASARA ESTO*/
@media all and (max-width: 1000px){
    .canales{
            width: 155px;
            height: 90px;
    }
}

/* CUANDO LA PANTALLA ES MENOR A 500px PASARA ESTO*/
@media all and (max-width: 300px){
    .canales{
        width: 140px;
        height: 70px;
        display:block;
        margin:auto;
    }
}

/* PARA QUE NO APAREZCAEL TAMAÑO ORIGINAL CUANDO YA ESTA EXTENDIDA LA VENTANA
DEL NAVEGADOR, COLOCAS UN TAMAÑO ESTABLECIDO, EN MI CASO 160px*/
 .canales{
     width: 170px;
     height: 100px;
     margin-bottom: 25px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     border-radius: 20px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     -o-border-radius: 20px;
     -ms-border-radius: 20px;
 }

 .canales_mas_ancho{
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
 }

 /* CUANDO LA PANTALLA ES MENOR A 1000px PASARA ESTO*/
 @media all and (max-width: 1000px){
    .canales_mas_ancho{
            width: 155px;
            height: 90px;
    }
 }

 /* CUANDO LA PANTALLA ES MENOR A 500px PASARA ESTO*/
 @media all and (max-width: 300px){
 .canales_mas_ancho{
        width: 140px;
        height: 70px;
        display:block;
        margin:auto;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question - it is difficult to understand from the amount of code you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you:
https://s.codepen.io/panchroma/debug/EbJdjM/jVMpogKwympk

This pen is the same HTML and CSS that you posted except that in the CSS for the .nav block, starting at line 46, I set a height for the .nav element.

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 55px !important;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

What seemed to be happening with your code is that on mobile viewports, .nav covered the entire window, and therefore you couldn't access the links because they are 'under' the fullscreen nav element. To confirm this, comment out line 50 which is limiting the height of .nav

Good luck!

Comment: Excellent @DaZ !